# Redirect *azurewebsites.net to .com but not for CDN

Tags: azure, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a Joomla site on Azure. I have set up the .com properly and I understand why the *azurewebsites.net URL is still working.

I wanted to redirect all traffic from *azurewebsites.net to the .com. I followed this guide and it works as intended.
http://onthecloud.azurewebsites.net/seo-tip-how-to-block-the-.azurewebsites.net-domain

However, I also have an Azure CDN in place (mycdn.azureedge.net/).  I use JCH Optimize to set up the CDN. I see the the calls to mycdn.azureedge.net/ are generated properly. However, somehow,  because of the web.config redirect, all the traffic is redirected from the CDN **back** to my .com, which defeats the purpose of the CDN. This creates a lot of redirect calls.

Is there a way to write the web.config lines to exclude the CDN?

Here's what my web.config looks like. When I delete those lines, the CDN redirects disappear, so the problem is really here.

```
<rule name="Disable Azure Domain" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.azurewebsites.net" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Can you share the urls for your site and cdn? I suspect you've set it up somehow that the input condition applies to both sites

Answer (score 0):

Look at your conditions. You're filtering all traffic that goes to "*.azurewebsites.net". All calls to your cdn fall into that filter as well, which is why you're seeing them be redirected:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.azurewebsites.net" />
</conditions>
```

Instead, filter the calls just to your website.  So your condition would look more like:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="yoursite.azurewebsites.net" />
</conditions>
```

That'll let calls to the CDN go through just fine.

You can find more details on setting up redirect rules for your Azure Web App here: http://zainrizvi.io/2016/04/07/block-default-azure-websites-domain/

Fyi, below is the full web.config that I use for my site. You'll not that I've set some of the other settings a bit differently. Try using that web.config file instead (just change the site names as appropriate) and see if it works for you.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
      <rules>  
        <rule name="Redirect to zainriziv.io" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />  
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^zainrizvi\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.zainrizvi.io/{R:0}" />  
        </rule>  
      </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Note: When you're testing the fix your browser might have cached the redirect, so you might want to try fiddler or a new browser/pc to verify things work as expected

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I added back the lines with pattern="yoursite.azurewebsites.net" and restarted my website. The CDN redirects are back. Here's what I get on GTMetrix/Pagespeed (several of those) : `Remove the following redirect chain if possible:



http://myendpoint.azureedge.net/images/dark_bg.jpg

http://www.example.com/images/dark_bg.jpg`

Comment: @PLapointe I just updated my answer with a more detailed example which works for my site. Give it a shot and see if that works for you